# How to solve "No credentials found for releases (did you mean `lein deploy clojars`?)"?

Tags: clojure, release, leiningen

I'm trying to deploy a (non-snapshot) library to Clojars using Leiningen. I've actually been able to deploy this library before but it was a while ago and  now I've made some fixes that I want to release. I even have a small bash script that used to handle the release and deploy process that essentially just do:

```
RELEASE_VERSION=${releaseVersion} lein release
```

Where `releaseVersion` is supplied as a parameter to the script. I'm using the [lein-release](https://github.com/relaynetwork/lein-release) plugin and I've specified:

```
:lein-release {:deploy-via :clojars}
```

in my `project.clj`. I also have working (or at least they used to work) GPG credentials in `/Users/johan/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg`.

When running `lein release` I'm prompted for my GPG password but after a couple of seconds I run into this:

```
$ RELEASE_VERSION=0.2.1 lein release
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
[master cf4e5d1] Version 0.2.1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Johan <email>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID ABC123431, created 2015-11-12

No credentials found for releases (did you mean `lein deploy clojars`?)
Password prompts are not supported when ran after other (potentially)
interactive tasks.
See `lein help deploy` for an explanation of how to specify credentials.
```

I've also tried setting `repositories` in my `project.clj`:

```
:repositories [["releases" {:url "http://clojars.org/repo" :creds :gpg}]]
```

But it doesn't make any difference. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had accidentally removed `[lein-release "1.0.9"]` from `{:user {:plugins .. }}` in my `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file. When I added it again everything worked as expected.